# how to remove unwanted space in div wrapping an img?

Tags: html, css, styles

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9JU3T/)

I have:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <img src='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/70/Peace_dove_icon.svg' width='50' height='50'>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div{
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

but if you inspect the page you should hopefully see a seemingly arbitrary `5px` extra on the bottom of the `div` tag.

how can I get rid of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the descender of the img. Images behave like words and sit on the baseline in the container, which leaves space below them for descenders.

Solution: give the img `display:block` or use properties like `vertical-align`, `position` or `float`, whichever suits the situation best.

I updated the fiddle - [new one](http://jsfiddle.net/9JU3T/2/) here - but I must say, there is no visible difference in this case. There is nothing on the screen except the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [vertical-align](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align) as by default, images are rendered inline, like a letter.

or set the `style="display: block;"`

Answer (score 0):

Just give the div this css rule:

```
height: 50px;
```

Here is a working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Hive7/9JU3T/1/

Answer (score 0):

`line-height:0;` for the div solves the problem, too!